# $x^2+x+2\equiv 0 \pmod {56}$ using CRT

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

If we have for example the equation: $x^2+x+2 \equiv 0 \pmod{56}$, I understand that we need to divide to 2 equations:

1. $x^2+x+2\equiv 0\pmod{8}$
2. $x^2+x+2 \equiv 0  \pmod{7}$

Then, how we unite the two results for the original equation?

Comment: First you have to solve the equations mod 7 and mod 8. Have you done that?

Comment: @Derivative Yes, for $mod 8$ is $x\equiv 2, 5$ and for $mod 7$ is $x\equiv 3$

Comment: Since you already mentioned CRT, perhaps take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_moduli

Comment: Since $\gcd(8,7)=1,$ if you have a pair $(a,b)$ where $a$ solves (1) and $b$ solves (2), then this pair generates a unique solution mod $56.$ Can find it by just searching all the elements of $\{0,1,...,55\}$ untill you get one which is $a$ mod $8$ and $b$ mod $7.$ That can be shortened as shown in most intro number theory texts.

Comment: You can use Hensel's Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

Comment: My first instinct was \begin{align*} x^2 + x + 2 & \equiv 0 \pmod{56}\\ \implies x^2 + x + 2 & \equiv 56 \pmod{56}\\  \implies x^2 + x + 2 & \equiv 112 \pmod{56}\\ \implies x^2 + x - 110 & \equiv 0 \pmod{56} \end{align*} The last equivalence can be factored over the integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already mentioned that you have find that
$$x\equiv 2,5 \text{ mod } 8 \text{ and } x\equiv 3 \text{ mod } 7 $$ are the solution then you've to find the solution that satisfy both. 
Hence for the first congruency if 2 is the solution then so is $2+8n$ hence 10 also satisfy the same. 
Now look for the second congruency , 3 is the solution then so is $3+7n$ hence 10 also satisfy the same. Therefore ,
$$x\equiv 10 \text{  mod } 56$$
Now again go back to first congruency. As 5 is the solution then so is $5+8n$ therefore try plug in the values so that this number is 3 more than a multiple of 7. Plug in $n=5$ gives $45$ which satisfy the first congruency. But also $45=7\cdot 6+3$ hence this is the other solution. 
Therefore the solution are :
$$x\equiv 10,45\text{ mod } 56$$